# javascript More link issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam having one javascript issue (error seems to be very small, BUT iam hitting hard to a wall for this small issue..

in this site: http://tangerine-ny.com/ , click 'team' --> you will see all people with their photos, if you click 'More' , you can see their profile just above, all photos of 'More' working except 'Liz Loder' More link..

Please check the code, here: http://jsfiddle.net/nWuNK/ ( there is no need to run, BUT just check the code in it)

PLease kindly someone look into this and provide me  a solution for that problem!

**HTML CODE:**

```
<html>
<head>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="stick">
            <div id="header">
                <a href="http://blog.tangerine-ny.com/" id="nav-blog">Blog</a>
                <a class="nav-seperator" id="nav-s"></a>
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/tangerineny" id="nav-youtube">YouTube Channel</a>
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="#team" id="nav-team">Team</a></li> <li class="nav-seperator"></li>
                    <li><a href="#clients" id="nav-client">Clients</a></li> <li class="nav-seperator"></li>
                    <li><a href="#partners" id="nav-partners">Partners</a></li> <li class="nav-seperator"></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" id="nav-contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- Header -->
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="colored-lines"></div>
            <h1><a href="#" id="logo" title="Tangerine NY">Tangerine NY</a></h1>


            <div id="home">
                <span id="home1">We </span> <a href="#partners"id="home-partners">partner</a>
                <span id="home5"> with </span> <a href="#clients" name="partners" id="home-clients">clients</a> 
                <span id="home6"> to place talent in planning, account</span>




                <div id="partners" style="display:none;">
                    <a href="#" id="partners-close">Close</a>
                    <span id="partners-left">We don't believe in a transactional placement business.  We believe in partnering with                         talent and clients alike to solve problems and address opportunities.  Our team brings deep and recent agency                       management experience, years of recruiting for the best creative agencies and a finger on the pulse of emerging talent.  
                    </span>
                    <span>We work as a team so each  of us benefits from the energy, connection and smarts of all of us.  Above all else, we value an honest dialogue with clients and talent alike and know that transparent dealing is the foundation of our many deep and                    long standing relationships.
                    </span>

                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!-- Partners -->




                <span id="home2">management, media/comms planning, creative technology, innovation and      leadership positions. Our core business is in</span>
                <span id="home-ie"> the agency world, however our </span>
                <a href="#team"  name="teams" id="home-team">team</a>
                <span id="home7"> also connects people<br /></span>

                <div id="team" style="display:none;">
                    <a href="#" name="team" id="team-close">Close</a>

                    <div id="sally" class="bio" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="bio-name">Sally Jones</div>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=902885592" class="facebook">Sally Jones Facebook</a>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/sallyvjones" class="twitter">Sally Jones Twitter</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:sally@tangerine-ny.com">sally@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                        <img src="images/b1.jpg" alt="Sally Jones" />
                        <p>Sally started her advertising career at Ogilvy London and went on to spend 10 years in account management before moving to New York and joining Kendall Tarrant in 1999. Whilst at KT NY Sally worked in the account management, creative and planning departments. In 2001 Sally founded Tangerine and since its launch Tangerine has worked on searches in the US, Australia, Europe and Asia.<br/><br><a href="http://blog.tangerine-ny.com/?p=1067" target="_blank"><i>10 Questions for Sally Jones</i></a>
<br />
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="kim" class="bio" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="bio-name">Kimberly Aguilera</div>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/kaguilera" class="linkedin">Kimberly Aguilera LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/kaguilera" class="twitter">Kimberly Aguilera Twitter</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:kimberly@tangerine-ny.com">kimberly@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                        <img src="images/b2.jpg" alt="Kimberly Aguilera" />
                        <p>Kimberly is recruiting in strategy, digital strategy, social and community at Tangerine. She is passionate about helping people make their next best career move by understanding their core skills, culture needs and what really makes them tick. Prior to joining Tangerine in NY in 2006, Kimberly graduated with a BS in marketing from San Diego State University and worked as a brand manager in San Diego.<br/><br><a href="http://blog.tangerine-ny.com/?p=1065" target="_blank"><i>10 Questions for Kimberly Aguilera</i></a>
<br />
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="lukas" class="bio" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="bio-name">Doug Sherrard</div>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/dsherrard" class="linkedin">Doug Sherrard LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dougsherrard" class="facebook">Doug Sherrard Facebook</a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/#!/dougsherrard" class="twitter">Doug Sherrard Twitter</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:doug@tangerine-ny.com">doug@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                        <img src="images/b3.jpg" alt="Doug" />
                        <p>Doug heads up Tangerine's creative and digital disciplines. He has a passion for technology, marketing, innovation and design. He strives to build long term value-add relationships with elite talent and progressive clients that lead these industries globally. Doug grew up in Zululand, South Africa, and completed his Bachelor of Commerce in Marketing and International Business in Sydney, Australia. He has worked in the UK, Thailand, Malaysia, Philippines, Indonesia and Australia.<br/><br><a href="http://blog.tangerine-ny.com/?p=1064" target="_blank"><i>10 Questions for Doug Sherrard</i></a>
<br />
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="alison" class="bio" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="bio-name">Alison Lord</div>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/alison-lord/0/39/457" class="linkedin">Alison Lord LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=678487625" class="facebook">Alison Lord Facebook</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:alison@tangerine-ny.com">alison@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                        <img src="images/b4.jpg" alt="Alison Lord" />
                        <p>Alison joined tangerine in January of 2010 and has worked on management level searches for clients in advertising, design, media owners and on the brand side to recruit creatively oriented strategic leadership talent. She spent 18 years in the agency business and worked in account management across a variety of clients at JWT and APL then spent 10 years at Lowe in classical HR, talent management and operations including finance and real estate. Having helped agency c-level management answer the questions that perhaps most challenged the conventions of the industry over the past decade, Alison brings a unique perspective to search.<br/><br><a href="http://blog.tangerine-ny.com/?p=1063" target="_blank"><i>10 Questions for Alison Lord</i></a>
<br />              <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="torrey" class="bio" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="bio-name">Torrey La Grange</div>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/alison-lord/0/39/457" class="linkedin">Torrey La Grange LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=678487625" class="facebook">Torrey La Grange Facebook</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:torrey@tangerine-ny.com">torrey@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                        <img src="images/b5.jpg" alt="Torrey La Grange" />
                        <p>Prior to joining Tangerine in 2010, Torrey built her career in account management at shops including TBWA\Chiat\Day, Secret Weapon in Los Angeles, Saatchi & Saatchi London and JWT New York. Torrey's extensive experience in the agency world, in shops both big and small, helps her bring a informed viewpoint to searches and allows her to better understand the needs of agencies in hiring talent.<br/><br><a href="http://blog.tangerine-ny.com/?p=1069" target="_blank"><i>10 Questions for Torrey La Grange</i></a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="liz" class="bio" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="bio-name">Liz Loder</div>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/lizloder" class="linkedin">Liz Loder LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/lizloder" class="twitter">Liz Loder Twitter</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:lloder@tangerine-ny.com">lloder@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                        <img src="images/b6.jpg" alt="Liz Loder" />
                        <p>Liz graduated from UVA in 2009 with a BA in economics and classics. She enjoyed a summer internship with Tangerine in 2008 and became a permanent part of the team in 2010, as project manager and research lead.<br/><br><a href="http://blog.tangerine-ny.com/?p=1066" target="_blank"><i>10 Questions for Liz Loder</i></a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="sandy" class="bio" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="bio-name">Sandy Williams</div>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/sandra-williams/4b/aa3/a5b" class="linkedin">Sandy Williams LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/sswill251" class="twitter">Sandy Williams Twitter</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:sandra@tangerine-ny.com">sandra@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                        <img src="images/b7.jpg" alt="Sandy Williams" />
                        <p>Sandy joined Tangerine in 2012 at their group assistant. She graduated from Boston College in 2010 with a BA in Islamic Civilizations and from NYU in 2012 with an MA in Art History.<br/><br><a href="http://blog.tangerine-ny.com/?p=1086" target="_blank"><i>10 Questions for Sandy Williams</i></a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="team-list">
                        <div class="person">
                            <a href="#" id="sally-i"><img src="images/t1.jpg" alt="Sally Jones" /></a>
                            <div class="short-bio">
                                <span class="team-name">Sally Jones</span>
                                <a href="mailto:sally@tangerine-ny.com">sally@tangerine-ny.com</a><br />
                                <a href="#teams" id="more-sally" class="team-more">More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="person">
                            <a href="#" id="kim-i"><img src="images/t2.jpg" alt="Kimberly Aguilera" /></a>
                            <div class="short-bio">
                                <span class="team-name">Kimberly Aguilera</span>
                                <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:kimberly@tangerine-ny.com">kimberly@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                                <a href="#" id="more-kim" class="team-more">More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="person" style="margin-right:0px">
                            <a href="#" id="lukas-i"><img src="images/t3.jpg" alt="Doug Sherrard" /></a>
                            <div class="short-bio">
                                <span class="team-name">Doug Sherrard</span>
                                <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:doug@tangerine-ny.com">doug@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                                <a href="#" id="more-lukas" class="team-more">More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="person">
                            <a href="#" id="alison-i"><img src="images/t4.jpg" alt="Alison Lord" /></a>
                            <div class="short-bio">
                                <span class="team-name">Alison Lord</span>
                                <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:alison@tangerine-ny.com">alison@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                                <a href="#" id="more-alison" class="team-more">More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="person">
                            <a href="#" id="torrey-i"><img src="images/t5.jpg" alt="Torrey La Grange" /></a>
                            <div class="short-bio">
                                <span class="team-name">Torrey La Grange</span>
                                <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:torrey@tangerine-ny.com">torrey@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                                <a href="#" id="more-torrey" class="team-more">More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="person" style="margin-right:0px">
                            <a href="#" id="liz-i"><img src="images/t6.jpg" alt="Liz Loder" /></a>
                            <div class="short-bio">
                                <span class="team-name">Liz Loder</span>
                                <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:lloder@tangerine-ny.com">lloder@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                                <a href="#" id="more-liz" class="team-more">More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="person" style="margin-right:0px">
                            <a href="#" id="sandy-i"><img src="images/t7.jpg" alt="Sandy Williams" /></a>
                            <div class="short-bio">
                                <span class="team-name">Sandy Williams</span>
                                <a class="team-mail" href="mailto:sandra@tangerine-ny.com">sandra@tangerine-ny.com</a>
                                <a href="#" id="more-sandy" class="team-more">More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div><!-- Team-List -->
                </div><!-- Team -->


                <span id="home3">to client side opportunities where creatively focused strategic</span><span id="home-ie2"> business talent has a transformative impact.  Please </span><a href="#contact" id="home-contact">contact</a>


                <div id="contact" style="display:none;">
                    <a href="#" name="contact" id="contact-close">Close</a>
                    <div id="contact-left">
                        <h2>TALENT</h2>
                        <form class="iphorm" action="contact-form/process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="iphorm-wrapper">
                                <div class="iphorm-inner">
                                    <div class="iphorm-message"><p>Please fill out the information below and upload your CV/resume. We'll be in touch as soon as possible.</p></div>
                                    <div class="iphorm-container">
                                        <input type="text" value="Name" name="name" id="contact-name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name'}" />
                                        <input type="text" value="Email" name="email" id="contact-mail" onfocus="if(this.value=='Email'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Email'}" />
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                        <span>Concentration:</span>
                                        <input id="box1" class="CheckBoxClass" name="concentration[]" value="Planning" type="checkbox" />
                                        <label for="box1" class="CheckBoxLabelClass">Planning</label>
                                        <input id="box2" class="CheckBoxClass" name="concentration[]" value="Account Management" type="checkbox" />
                                        <label for="box2" class="CheckBoxLabelClass" >Account Management</label>  
                                        <input id="box3" class="CheckBoxClass" name="concentration[]" value="Media/Comms Planning" type="checkbox" />
                                        <label for="box3" class="CheckBoxLabelClass">Media/Comms Planning</label>
                                        <input id="box4" class="CheckBoxClass" name="concentration[]" value="Creative" type="checkbox" />
                                        <label for="box4" class="CheckBoxLabelClass">Creative</label>
                                        <input id="box5" class="CheckBoxClass" name="concentration[]" value="Innovation" type="checkbox" />
                                        <label for="box5" class="CheckBoxLabelClass">Innovation</label>
                                        <input id="box6" class="CheckBoxClass" name="concentration[]" value="Other" type="checkbox" />
                                        <label for="box6" class="CheckBoxLabelClass">Other</label>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                        <input class="file_1"  type="file" name="upload" />
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                        <div style="display:none;" class="element-wrapper captcha-element-wrapper clearfix"><label for="type_the_word">Type the word</label><input id="type_the_word" class="captcha-element" type="text" name="type_the_word" /></div>
                                        <input type="submit" id="contact-submit" name="contact" value="Submit" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div><!-- Contact Left -->
                    <div id="contact-right">
                        <h2>CLIENTS</h2>
                        <p>Please contact us at <a href="mailto:hello@tangerine-ny.com">hello@tangerine-ny.com</a>. One of our team will be in touch to talk about how we can help.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!-- Contact -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/file.js"></script>

                <span id="home4">us if you would like to learn more.</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div><!-- Home -->




            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!-- Content -->
    </div><!-- Wrapper -->
    <div id="footer"></div><!-- Footer -->


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['setAccount', 'UA-21327235-1']); gaq.push(['trackPageview']);
        (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); })();
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

**Javscript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".CheckBoxClass").change(function(){if($(this).is(":checked")){$(this).next("label").addClass("LabelSelected")}else{$(this).next("label").removeClass("LabelSelected")}});

        $("#logo").click(function () {
            $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-clients').show().css("opacity","1").css("zoom","0");
            $('#team, #partners, #contact, #clients').slideUp("fast");
        });


        var anchor = jQuery.url.attr('anchor');


        if (anchor == 'clients') {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 200}, 1000);
            $('#team, #partners, #contact').hide();
            $("#clients").slideDown("slow");
            $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
            $('#home-clients').css("opacity","1");
            $('#home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact').css("text-decoration","underline");
        }
        if (anchor == 'contact') {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 650}, 1000);
            $('#partners, #clients, #team').hide();
            $("#contact").slideDown("slow");
            $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-team, #home-clients, #home-partners, #home-ie, #home-ie2, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
            $('#home-contact').css("opacity","1");
            $('#home-team, #home-clients, #home-partners').css("text-decoration","underline");
        }
        if (anchor == 'team') {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
            $("#team").slideDown("slow");
            $('#partners, #clients, #contact').hide();
            $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-clients, #home-partners, #home-contact, #home-ie, #home-ie2, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
            $('#home-team').css("opacity","1");
            $('#home-clients, #home-partners, #home-contact').css("text-decoration","underline");
        }
        if (anchor == 'partners') {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 50}, 1000);
            $("#partners").slideDown("slow");
            $('#team, #clients, #contact').hide();
            $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-clients, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-ie, #home-ie2, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
            $('#home-partners').css("opacity","1");
            $('#home-clients, #home-team, #home-contact').css("text-decoration","underline");
        }


        $("#home-clients, #nav-client").click(function () {
            if ($("#clients").is(":hidden")) {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 200}, 1000);
                $('#team, #partners, #contact').hide();
                $("#clients").slideDown("slow");
                $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
                $('#home-clients').css("text-decoration","none");
                $('#home-clients').css("opacity","1");
            } else {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
                $("#clients").slideUp(500);
                $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-clients, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 1);
            }
        });

        $("#home-contact, #nav-contact").click(function () {
            if ($("#contact").is(":hidden")) {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 650}, 1000);
                $('#partners, #clients, #team').hide();
                $("#contact").slideDown("slow");
                $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-team, #home-clients, #home-partners, #home-ie, #home-ie2, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
                $('#home-contact').css("text-decoration","none");
                $('#home-contact').css("opacity","1");
            } else {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
                $('#partners, #clients, #team').hide();
                $("#contact").slideUp("slow");
                $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-clients, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 1);
            }
        });


        $("#home-team, #nav-team").click(function () {
            if ($("#team").is(":hidden")) {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
                $("#team").slideDown("slow");
                $('#partners, #clients, #contact').hide();
                $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-clients, #home-partners, #home-contact, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
                $('#home-team').css("opacity","1");
            } else {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
                $("#team").slideUp("slow");
                $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-clients, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 1);
                $('#sally, #kim, #lukas, #alison, #torrey, #liz').hide();
            }
        });

        $("#home-partners, #nav-partners").click(function () {
            if ($("#partners").is(":hidden")) {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 50}, 1000);
                $("#partners").slideDown("slow");
                $('#team, #clients, #contact').hide();
                $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-clients, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
                $('#home-partners').css("text-decoration","none");
                $('#home-partners').css("opacity","1");
                $('#home-clients, #home-team, #home-contact').css("text-decoration","underline");
            } else {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
                $("#partners").slideUp("slow");
                $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-clients, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 1);
            }
        });



        $("#clients").hover(
          function () {
            $("#clients-close").show();
          },
          function () {
             $("#clients-close").hide();
          }
        );





        $("#partners-close").click(function () {
            $('#partners').slideUp("slow");
            $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-clients, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $('#home-team, #home-clients, #home-partners, #home-contact').css("text-decoration","underline");
        });
        $("#team-close").click(function () {
            $('#team').slideUp("slow");
            $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-clients, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $('#sally, #kim, #lukas, #alison, #torrey, #liz').hide();
        });
        $("#contact-close").click(function () {
            $('#contact').slideUp("slow");
            $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-clients, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 1);
        });

        $("#clients-close").click(function () {
            $('#clients').slideUp("slow");
            $('#home1, #home2, #home3, #home4, #home5, #home6, #home7, #home-partners, #home-team, #home-contact, #home-clients, #home-ie, #home-ie2').fadeTo("slow", 1);
        });



        $("#more-sally, #sally-i").click(function () {
            if ($("#kim, #lukas, #alison, #torrey, #liz").is(":visible")) {
                $('#sally').fadeIn("slow");
                $('#kim, #lukas, #alison, #torrey, #liz').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 300);
            } else {
                $('#kim, #lukas, #alison, #torrey, #liz').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
                $('#sally').slideDown("slow");
            }
        });

        $("#more-kim, #kim-i").click(function () {
            if ($("#sally, #lukas, #alison, #torrey, #liz").is(":visible")) {
                $('#kim').fadeTo("slow", 1);
                $('#sally, #lukas, #alison, #torrey, #liz').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
            } else {
                $('#sally, #lukas, #alison, #torrey, #liz').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
                $('#kim').slideDown("slow");
            }
        });

        $("#more-lukas, #lukas-i").click(function () {
            if ($("#sally, #kim, #alison, #torrey, #liz").is(":visible")) {
                $('#lukas').fadeTo("slow", 1);
                $('#sally, #kim, #alison, #torrey, #liz').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
            } else {
                $('#sally, #kim, #alison, #torrey, #liz').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
                $('#lukas').slideDown("slow");
            }
        });


        $("#more-alison, #alison-i").click(function () {
            if ($("#sally, #kim, #lukas, #torrey, #liz").is(":visible")) {
                $('#alison').fadeTo("slow", 1);
                $('#sally, #kim, #lukas, #torrey, #liz').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
            } else {
                $('#sally, #kim, #lukas, #torrey, #liz').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
                $('#alison').slideDown("slow");
            }
        });

        $("#more-torrey, #torrey-i").click(function () {
            if ($("#sally, #kim, #lukas, #alison, #liz").is(":visible")) {
                $('#torrey').fadeTo("slow", 1);
                $('#sally, #kim, #lukas, #alison, #liz').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
            } else {
                $('#sally, #kim, #lukas, #alison, #liz').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
                $('#torrey').slideDown("slow");
            }
        });

        $("#more-liz, #liz-i").click(function () {
            if ($("#sally, #kim, #lukas, #alison, #torrey").is(":visible")) {
                $('#liz').fadeTo("slow", 1);
                $('#sally, #kim, #lukas, #alison, #torrey').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
            } else {
                $('#sally, #kim, #lukas, #alison, #torrey').hide();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 350}, 1000);
                $('#liz').slideDown("slow");
            }
        });




        $(function() {
          $("input.file_1").filestyle({ 
              image: "images/contact-browse.png",
              imageheight : 28,
              imagewidth : 68,
              width : 100
          });
        });


    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Its generally asked that you post the code here rather than linking to external sites.  People are much more likely to answer your question helpfully if they see you've taken the time to put it together in a readable and useful way.

Comment: Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/) **here**. Try to isolate the problem and post just enough code so we can reproduce it.

Comment: @bfavaretto I added my code above now, please check and tell me what went wrong..?

Comment: @Rick: How about just posting the relevant part? Nobody want's to wade through your entire code unless you're paying them. Also, what does "not work" mean? Is there an error message? Does it do nothing at all? Does it do something unexpected?

Comment: @MattBurland when I click 'More' link for a profile 'Liz' , it should its profile, but thats not happening.. any idea please?

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Fri, 11 Jan 2013 18:51:24 UTC


Message: '_gaq' is undefined
Line: 310
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://tangerine-ny.com/

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Could you please explain me what it tells? (I mean something you've posted in your comment).. Now what I've to do..?

Comment: @Rick - you have an undefined variable that is being used, and causing an error.

Answer (score 2):

There's no click event listener attached to `#more-liz`.

I see that you have this:

```
$("#more-liz, #liz-i").click(function () {
    // ...
});
```

However, this is not attached. Are you sure tangerine.js matches the source code you've posted here? Try using the actual source code instead of your minified file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is something fishy going on here.  In the posted code you show 6 click attachments for the popup functionality but there are 7 places to click.  What the names should be cause what I'm not sure (I don't know these people) but it is working as expected -- 6 things you click on make stuff pop up.

Congrats.  No bug.

Comment: Yes you're right! So what I have to do now? pls suggest me..

Comment: @Rick - You know what the people look like, figure out which one you are missing and add it in.